# What is the solution for low signal coverage, a better transmition or getting better receiver/(antenna/dish)?

Tags: router, wireless, isp

We have a remote site, were a 4G/LTE Industrial/Rugged router/Gateway is installed, but we always suffer from temporarily disconnections and lag, the engineers say its installed in low coverage area.. although they are not Telecom specialized. I'm thinking if I were to improve communication performance. its either form the ISP side. so they for example increase the signal strength or install extra Telecom-Towers or we just have to get better Receiver as in high gain antennas.. for example.
My question is, what are my practical realistic solutions/options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely your ISP can/will do something for you. They can't simply ramp up the power, usually they're already running the maximum power allowed (depending on link quality).

With wireless, your best option is to install a directional antenna, increasing both receiver gain and effective transmitter power. Make sure you get an antenna that's most effective in the band you're using. If the scenario permits a good antenna will solve the problem.

Alternatively, you can look out for other connection options. Maybe LTE isn't the only one.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by other connection options, like fiber or 802.11?

Comment: In the U.S., antenna gain is regulated by the FCC, so you must be careful about doing that. If you get too much gain, you could be fined and have your equipment confiscated. The gain allowed for a directional antenna is greater than for an omni-directional antenna, but there are still limits.

Comment: If the antenna is indoors move it outside. If that's not an option get a type of cell phone extender and put a directional antenna pointing to the tower of your carrier. The company you by the extender/repeater from will help design it. You'll need 2-3 bars of coverage where your outside antenna will go and you want to keep the cables length from the outside antenna to the repeater as short as possible. You'd have an indoor antenna as well. I've used repeaterstore.com but there are many good ones. It's not a refrence to use them, just a place to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you "Fixitrod", but I would't need a repeater or internal antenna, as the goal is to connect our remote system to the network, unless these solution requires special power input from the repeater to work. like they demand higher power input. but what would the effect of surrounding the antenna with metallic enclosure do? with one side open for ventilation, would it function as Faraday cage and weaken the signal?

Comment: @navigator Well, anything else - maybe something else is even more attractive. In addition to Fixitrod's suggestion, I'd prefer moving the mobile router to where the antenna is (outside and if necessary on a mast) - less complex and not another SPOF. Directionalizing an omni-directional antenna is possible, but requires RF skills and isn't usually "sturdy".

Comment: I accepted this answer because it make sense, but we yet to actually implement it, as soon as i have any updates i will be adding to benefit everybody!.